# Do I need to bond and ground where the CSST connects to the metal pipe?

Tags: electrical, gas, grounding-and-bonding, csst

I recently had my gas line moved for my range. The piping was replaced with CSST.

If my metal piping is already bonded and grounded near the gas meter, do I need to also have a separate bond and ground clamp on the fitting where the CSST meets the metal pipe?

Answer (score 2):

According to a [home inspection site that I've found useful in the past](https://structuretech.com/bonding-csst-2/), the answer is "**no**, you do not need a bonding clamp to ground on the CSST fitting" **as long as** the upstream metal pipe is properly grounded **according to current code** on the house side of the gas meter.  The CSST manufacturer may have additional requirements.

From the home inspection site (company located in Minnesota USA):

> If CSST is installed without being properly bonded to current standards, you have an increased risk for damage to the material from a nearby lightning strike. If CSST is damaged, it can leak gas and cause an explosion and/or a fire.

If your house grounding system is not up to current code in terms of minimum diameter of the conductor to ground and the ground/soil contact of the grounding electrodes, you may have to upgrade your grounding system or the bonding of the gas pipe to that system. As of 2022, minimum grounding system would be at least two 8-foot-length conductive rods driven into the ground no less than 6 feet apart, bonded to each other and electrical panel with 6 gauge or larger copper ground wire (depending on amperage of service), or other code-specified alternative.